# Combining two python scripts to run as one program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two python scripts that I would like to combine and run as one program. But I am unsure about what exactly do I need to alter to make to the two scripts work together.

Here is my first code:

```
import random
with open('filename.txt') as fin:
   lines = fin.readlines()
   random.shuffle(lines)
   for i, line in enumerate(lines):
      if i >= 0 and i < 6800:
          print(line, end='')
```

And here is the second:

```
import csv
with open ("Randomfile.txt") as f:
   dict1 = {}
   r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
   for row in r:

      a, b, v = row
      dict1.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

   #for key in dict1:
      #print(key[0])
      #print(key[1])
      #print(d[key][0]])

with open ("filename2.txt") as f:
   dict2 = {}
   r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
   for row in r:

      a, b, v = row
      dict2.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

  #for key in dict2:
     #print(key[0])

   count = 0
   for key1 in dict1:
      for key2 in dict2:
         if (key1[0] == key2[0]) and abs((float(key1[1].split(" ")[0])) - (float(key2[1].split(" ")[0]))) < 0:
           count += 1

print(count)
```

What I usually do is using the first code, I extract a random set of elements. I then save it as a text file, open it in the second code and compare it with my other file to get my results.

However, I would essentially like to skip the saving and reopening process. I want to place my first script in my second and alter the code to make it run as one. So that when my elements are extracted, they are then automatically compared to my other file.

I have read up and watched videos about using

```
 if __name__==__main__
```

But I don't really understand its function. So if that is the solution, I would love to understand how to use it in solving my problem.

Please help my figure out how I can combine the two scripts, altering them both to have the code run as one. I happy to cooperate and clarify anything.

**[EDIT]** My files are in the following format.

An example of my random file:

```
  3 10045   0.120559958
  4 157465  0.590642951
  1 222471  0.947959795
  3 222473  0.083341617
  2 222541  0.054014337
  5 222588  0.060296547
```

An example of my other file (that i am comparing to my random file):

```
  2 143521109   4.57E-08
  1 201466556   5.57E-08
  1 11566373    8.43E-08
  1 143627370   8.61E-08
  6 98624499    1.02E-07
```

Comment: I don't understand how your results from part 1 combine with part 2: in part 1, you just print out the lines of `filename.txt` in random order. What does that have to do with part 2?

Comment: After I print the random lines I save it as a text file. After that, I open my second code and compare that saved text file with another file. Instead of extracting and saving text files, I would like to combine the two codes. So that when the random lines are extracted, they are automatically compared to my other file. @Evert If you read the first code correctly you would see that it only prints 6800 lines. So every time run the code it randomly prints 6800 different lines from the file.

Comment: I don't see the random lines being saved as a text file anywhere. If you're doing that manually through e.g. redirecting your stdout or even copy-pasting, you should mention that. But it's not clear from your question how the first part connects to the second part, other than that the second part opens a file called `Randomfile.txt`.

Comment: What do you mean you don't see random files saved as a text file anywhere. Is saving a python script as a text file something I have to physically show in my program? I didn't think so. In the first paragraph under my second code, I said that after I extract random lines I then save my results as a text file. After that, I then open that saved text file in my second program to compare to another file. I really don't see what is so confusing sir @Evert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I modified your code as follows:

```
import csv
import random

with open('filename.txt') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
    random.shuffle(lines)

    rnd_str = []
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if i >= 0 and i < 6800:
            rnd_str.append(line)

    r = rnd_str

    dict1 = {}
    for row in r:
        a, b, v = row.split()
        dict1.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

with open ("filename2.txt") as f:
    dict2 = {}
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")        

    dict2 = {}
    for row in r:
        a, b, v = row.split()
        dict2.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

    count = 0
    for key1 in dict1:
        for key2 in dict2:
            if (key1[0] == key2[0]) and ((float(key1[1]) - (float(key2[1]))) < 0):
                count += 1

print(count)
```

Thus you have no need to save the random file and you can process its content in the second part of the code i.e. comparing with the other file's content.

Note: it was a raw in your code:

```
abs((float(key1[1].split(" ")[0])) - (float(key2[1].split(" ")[0]))) < 0
```

that made me smile, because how can be the `abs(x) < 0`?

Anyway the script works now it results `4` upon the samples you gave.

Comment: Thanks for this this answer the other day. I have been using your suggestions but Im having one problem. Now when I run the code, I keep getting a value of 0. And I can't figure out why that is. No matter if I change the `< 0:` (is less than zero) number. For example if i write `< 10000` i am still getting a value of 0 which shouldnt be. @GyörgySolymosi

Comment: Please provide i. e. copy paste or other share some files or lists which are a possible input to reproduce the result and I find out.

Comment: If you meant provide an example of the files i am using, I just provided an example in my question above @GyörgySolymosi

Comment: An example fro Randomfile.txt too

Comment: Ive provided an example of both files. My random file and an example of the file i am comparing it to. They are both in the same format consisting of three columns each @GyörgySolymosi

Answer (score 6):

Imagine that instead of having two scripts, each script was a function and then they were both called from another function.

In other words, you would have the following:

```
def first_code():
   ...code of first script goes here...

def second_code():
   ...code of second script goes here...

def master_function():
    first_code()
    second_code()
```

Now, if master_function() is called, so are the other two.  If you replace that definition with main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    first_code()
    second_code()
```

It will automatically run if you execute the script from your command line.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation @dmargol can't get any more simpler than that. To some extent I think I understand.

Comment: As a newbie I approve of this style of scripting.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of printing in the first program try to create a dictionary from that output and then you can work with that dict instead of copying output, saving and loading again. You will save a lot of time.
So in the first file try to create a dict and change print into append to that dict. You don't need another script, just extend the first one with the code from second one working with duct instead of new file.

Answer (score -1):

Don't Worry. There's no need to alter your code. Just make a new script and put this in it:

```
def code1():
    import firstprogram

def code2():
    import secondprogram

code1()
code2()
```

This will run your first program and the your second. Just make sure to replace ***firstprogram*** and ***secondprogram*** with the names of your two programs.

Answer (score -2):

One thing you can do is type in the second file name in the main file. For example, my first file name is 'main.py' and the second one is 'float.py' you can merge these file together by typing:
`_merge_ = 'float.py'`
in the main file, which is 'main.py'
Hope it works!!

Thanking you all in advance.

Regards,
VC

Comment: Adding `_merge_ = 'float.py'` will do  nothing in Python, except assign the string `'float.py'` to the name `_merge_`.  Where have you seen this?